# How to check the value of various components of a HTML form after submission

Tags: html, forms

I have the below HTML form code for which i want to inspect the value of its various components after i submit it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>New user registration</title>
    <meta name="Description" content="New user registration page">
    <meta name="Author" content="Subhayan Bhattacharya">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/new_user_register">
User Name: <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName"></input><br /><br />
Email Address: <input type="email" id="emailAddress" name="email"></input><br /><br />
Password: <input type="password"  id="password" name="password"></input><br /><br />
Occupation:<br /><br />
<select id="occupation" name="occupation">
<option label="Developer" value="dev"></option>
<option label="Designer" value="design"></option>
<option label="Marketer" value="marketer"></option>
</select>
<br /><br />
Gender:
<br />
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">Male</input>
<input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female" checked>Female</input>
<br /><br />
Others:
<input type="checkbox" id="opt1" name="others" value="opt1">First option</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="opt2" name="others" value="opt2">Second option</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="opt3" name="others" value="opt3">Third option</input>
<br /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way i can do that in Chrome ? I have tried using developer tool but i could not check the key, value pairs.

Do i have to install a plugin or something to do it.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, press F12 to open the developer tools. Go to the "network" tab. Tick the "preserve log" button. Submit your form. You will see the postback request appear in the list. Click on it, look in the "headers" section and go right to the bottom to the "Form Data" section, you should see all the fields that the form submitted and what values they contained.

The process is very similar in the other major browsers too.

Comment: I can't see anything in the list after i have done the needful and pressed on submit. Do i have to add any plugin ?

Comment: No it's all part of the default install. You should see an entry on the left hand side labelled "new_user_register" or similar, which you can click on. Bear in mind the tools must be open _before_ you submit the form, and "preserve log" must be ticked in order for a non-ajax postback to show up. Also the "All" option must be chosen in the header bar. If you still don't see anything, it seems like the form maybe is not actually submitting somehow. Does clicking the submit button actually refresh your page? If you debug your server-side, does show that you visited that URL?

Comment: I am confused , if i type something in the google search bar and click on search with the developer tools turned on , i can see data there. But in this case i am creating a web application in my local machine. The page gets refreshed and generates the right response but the responses don't leave my computer, is that the case ?

Comment: technically correct, but regardless it still should generate a HTTP request to localhost. It still behaves in a client-server fashion - the client being the browser, and the server being your local HTTP server. The fact they're on the same physical host is not particularly relevant.

Comment: I can see it now. I think i did not select the "All" option. Thanks a million.